# Php, How to pass address of a clicked image to another php file

Tags: php, html, image

is there any way in Php that when you click on a link, or an image, the address of that image would pass to another Php page so that I can use it ?

I have this code that I have a gallery, and when people click on one of the images in this gallery I want another page to be opened what the sub images of that project,

this is the general gallery view :
[image]

and when one of these images is clicked on, I need this page to be opened, note that each image on the main gallery has its own sub gallery.
[image]

I can do this in a complete static method, but I need to make it fully dynamic..

So summary of my question is that, Can i possibly pass the address of the images on the first gallery to the second gallery page so that I can pull out the images that are related to that gallery in the database?

thanks in advance.

Comment: @hanky, but how? that's my question

Comment: Yes, you must put all required data inside a link's href attribute - for example page id - http://yourdoma.in/page/14

Comment: @MustafaAzad: you'll probably get better response if you include the relevant PHP code for the gallery view. By including your code you show what you've already accomplished. This will make it easier for people reading your question to see what you mean and to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this task.

One most popular way is pass image ID or Name through url like this

```
<a href="page.php?photoid=1234"><img src="1234.jpg" /></a>
```

Then use following code in your page.php to embed your image.

```
<?php $photoId = isset($_REQUEST['photoId']) ? $_REQUEST['photoId'] : null; ?>
<img src="<?php echo ($photoId != null) ? 'path/' . $photoId . '.jpg' : 'path/default.jpg'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value in the link. Suffix your link with  ?*variable*=value .

You can access it by $_GET['*variable*']

Answer (score 0):

Why not give it a link? such as

```
<a href="page.php?photoId=1223232"><img src="xxx" /></a>
```

Then in your page.php

```
$photoId = isset($_REQUEST['photoId']) ? $_REQUEST['photoId'] : null;
```

Comment: Not much familiar with that code, so correct me if I am wrong, but I need some sort of a code that has either the address,id,caption of the clicked on image on the next php file, because through one of those I can retrieve the sub images of the sub gallery, I hope i made it clear, tell me if I didn't please

Comment: I Now got the idea, thanks guys it did help, I cant vote up your comments cause I don't have enough reputation points sorry..